# Python- Unwanted Unicode characters in printing/extracting text from pdf

Tags: python, unicode

I am using Python 3.5.2/ Anaconda 4.1.1 to extract text from a pdf: (http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdf/10.1162/INOV_a_00153) using pypdf2. 
I am getting many of these unicode characters in the middle of the printed text that i do not require:

```
\xc5 \xef \x82 \xef \xac \n.
```

Can you please help me get rid of these pesky characters?! Thanks for your help!
This is my short piece of code below:

```
import PyPDF2


pdfFileObj = open('C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\Datasets\\task1_rb.pdf','rb')   

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

num=pdfReader.numPages

for a in range(1,num):

    text=''

    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(a)         

    text=pageObj.extractText().encode('utf-8')

    print(text)
```

Comment: you probably want to have `\n`, because this is a newline character

Comment: `print( text.decode('utf-8') )` however there are some mistakes in characters (on my machine), e.g. `… ﬁverticalsﬂŠfor …` instead of `… “verticals”—for …` on the 1st page.

Comment: Thanks! that seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could encode `text` in ASCII and ignore non-ASCII characters.

Try changing:

`text=pageObj.extractText().encode('utf-8')`

To:

`text=pageObj.extractText().encode('ascii', 'ignore')`

I've skimmed the output and it seems to have done the trick.

On a separate point, the `range` in your `for` loop is causing you to miss some of the output (unless that's what was intended).

Change `for a in range(1,num):` to `for a in range(0,num):`

Comment: Great stuff. If it helped, remember to accept the answer.