# python PyPDF2 - Special characters are printing while tring to print text from pdf file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, file-handling, pypdf

I am trying to print text from the [pdf file](https://pdfhost.io/v/Og478BOA_UNIT4pdf.pdf) using PyPDF2 module but some special characters are printing.
[already tried this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44087872/python-unwanted-unicode-characters-in-printing-extracting-text-from-pdf) but it does not seems to work.
**code**

```py
import PyPDF2

obj = open('/home/sarthak/Documents/UNIT-4.pdf','rb')

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(obj)

print(pdfReader.numPages)   #printing No. of pages

pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)

print(pageObj.extractText().encode('ascii','ignore'))    #also used 'utf-8' but doesn't work either

obj.close()
```

**output**

```
17
b'\n\n\n\n!#$\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n  \n\n"%$\n\n\n"#\n\n\n $\n\n\n\'())(*+, -$&\n\n\n\n\n $&-\n $\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

For removing /n u can pass the result in textacy.

```
import textacy
data=textacy.preprocess.remove_punct(section, marks='\n'))
print(data)
```

where`section` is the extracted data

for installing textacy `pip install textacy`